# ASP.NET MVC3 a viable choice for a large inventory-management type system?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This system would be used to manage sales, parts, repairs, follow-ups, leads etc for car dealers. It would need to be able to receive feeds via web services, expose web services, etc. I ask because I've heard some people say that traditional ASP is better for this type of system. If so, I'd be interested in the 'why' and 'how' of it.

Comment: You should consider integrating an ERP into your business or customize one. There is no reason to create this as a stand alone product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't be a good choice.  The MVC component is really just a user interface pattern - how requests to the system are handled, how pages are chosen and rendered, etc.  The business side (back end) of the application would likely be the same or very similar to a web forms app.